# C# WinRT Data Binding to "this" or using the index of the item within a collection

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, data-binding, windows-runtime

I'm using WinRT and .Net 4.5. I've got a ListView with ItemTemplates that have their data members bound to different fields in the item for each row. Let's call my collection `Series` and then items in the series are called `Item`.

My rows have text fields in them and I am receiving TextChanged events on those fields. I want to be able to update the `Item` in my collection. When I've implemented this for iOS or Mac, I would set the `tag` on the textfield to the index of the `Item`. That way when I received the TextChanged event, I could lookup the `Item` by index and then update my data model.

For WinRT, the `Tag` object on the `TextBox` is of type `object`, so I figured I could possibly bind the `Tag` field directly to my `Item` object. Then I wouldn't have to look it up from the `Series` it would just be available directly from the `sender` in my event method.

I tried using `Tag="{Binding this}"` but that resulted in `Tag` still being null during the event handler.

Is there a way to bind the `Tag`s in each row to my `Item` object in the `Series`?

```
<TextBox x:Name="Initial_InputAmount" Tag="{Binding this}" 
    Text="{Binding amountString}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="0, 0, 10, 0" Width="120" TextChanged="textChangedAmount"/>
```

Alternatively, is there a way I can Bind to the index of the item in the ListView, something like:

```
Tag="{Binding indexOfThis}"
```

because that would enable me to easily lookup my `Item` from the `Series` during my event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just leave

```
Tag="{Binding}"
```

It will bind to the current DataContext of the item - your viewmodel.

But I am not sure that you really need it - rather than using textChangedAmount event to change your model(viewmodel) you can just handle all changes on property setters:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public String amountString 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return this._amountString;
        };
        set
        { 
            if (this._amountString == value)
                return;

            HandleChanges(value);

            this._amountString = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("amountString");
        }
    }
}
```